# What triggers/resolves first, an effect from a creature dying or an effect from a creature going into the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm trying to use [Verdant Succession](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVerdant%20Succession%5d) with only one copy of [Worldspine Wurm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWorldspine%20Wurm%5d) in my deck.

Worldspine Wurm automatically goes back in the library *when it is put into the graveyard.* Verdant Succession lets me look for a copy of a creature in my library and put it into play *when a creature dies.* So, does Worldspine Wurm end up back in my library in time for me to search for it, or no?

Also, how would this be different with a creature that says *if it would* be put into a graveyard, it gets put back into my library *instead*, like [Darksteel Colossus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDarksteel%20Colossus%5d), instead of just saying *when* like Worldspine Wurm?

Comment: I rephrased your question about Darksteel Colossus a bit to try to preserve some of the exact wording on the card, since the wording is fairly specific and has rules meaning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You choose the order in which the abilities resolve, so you will be able to search for the Worldspine Wurm with Verdant Succession.

[Rule 700.4](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/General_(Additional_rules)) defines "dies":

> The term dies means “is put into a graveyard from the battlefield.”

This means that Worlspine Wurm's ability triggers "when Worldspine Wurm is put into a graveyard from anywhere" and Verdant Succession's ability triggers "whenever a green nontoken creature [is put into a graveyard from the battlefield]". So, of course, if a Worldspine Wurm is put into a graveyard from the battlefield, both of those conditions are met, so both aiblities trigger simultaneously. Then [rule 603.3b](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Handling_triggered_abilities) says

> **If multiple abilities have triggered since the last time a player received priority, each player, in APNAP order, puts triggered abilities he or she controls on the stack *in any order he or she chooses.*** (See rule 101.4.) Then the game once again checks for and resolves state-based actions until none are performed, then abilities that triggered during this process go on the stack. This process repeats until no new state-based actions are performed and no abilities trigger. Then the appropriate player gets priority.

So, if you choose to put the Worldspine Wurm's ability on the stack on top of the Verdant Succession's ability, the Wurm's ability will resolve first and it will move to the library, then the Verdant Succession's ability will resolve and you will be able to search for it.

---

If the Worldspine Wurm's ability was instead worded like the ability on Darksteel Colossus, then it would be a [replacement effect](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Replacement_effects) (the key word indicating that is "instead"). In that case, it would go to the library *instead of* the graveyard, so, as the definition above implies, it never "dies" and Verdant Succession's ability never triggers.

---

I would like to note that if the Verdant Succession and Worldspine Wurm are controlled by different players, the outcome of the Worldspine Wurm dying will depend on whose turn it is instead of any choices a player might make. Rule 603.3b says that triggered abilities controlled by different players are put on the stack in APNAP order, which is defined in [rule 101.4](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/The_magic_golden_rules):

> If multiple players would make choices and/or take actions at the same time, the active player (the player whose turn it is) makes any choices required, then the next player in turn order (usually the player seated to the active player’s left) makes any choices required, followed by the remaining nonactive players in turn order. Then the actions happen simultaneously. This rule is often referred to as the “Active Player, Nonactive Player (APNAP) order” rule.

This means that the abilities are put on the stack in turn order starting with the active player, so they resolve in reverse turn order. If that resolution order happens to make the Worldspine Wurm's ability resolve first, you can find it when searching.

Comment: Verdant Succession will trigger for everyone's nontoken green creatures - it might be relevant to consider the cases where someone else's Worldspine Wurm is dying (and when).

Comment: Great answer, quite comprehensive. Never knew the definition of dying before.

Comment: @HaoYe I added a note about that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the player controlling both effects, since "put into the graveyard" and "a creature dies" define the same thing, you decide the order in which they are put on the stack.

Place the effect from Verdant Succession on the stack first, and Worldspire Wurm's effect on top of it.

Worldspire Wurm will resolve first, putting it into the library. Next, Verdant Succession will resolve, looking for a card of the same name.

With Worldspire Wurm, Verdant Succession, and a sacrifice outlet, you could make infinite 5/5's.

For Darksteel Colossus, it is a replacement effect instead of a triggered effect. It never touches the graveyard.